# Signed process of simple symmetric random walk

Tags: random-walk

$X_i$ be a simple symmetric random walk. $Y_i= \operatorname{sign}(X_i)$. Define $Z_n= \sum_{i=1}^{n} Yi$. 
What is an upper bound on $Var(Z_n)$?

I feel the main issue is that $Y_i$ are not independent. Maybe there is some martingale hidden around which I’m not sure.

Comment: What is $sign(0)$? Is it 0 or 1 or -1?

Comment: It is $0$. But should it actually affect the answer?

Comment: With $sign(0)=0$ and assuming $X_1=0$ then we get $E[Z_n]=0$ for all $n$ and so $$Var(Z_n)=E[Z_n^2]=\sum_{i=2}^nP[X_n\neq 0] + \sum_{i,j \in \{2, ..., n\}, i\neq j} E[Y_iY_j]$$ and the right-hand-side is at most $(n-1) + (n-1)(n-2) =(n-1)^2$.